# Can't put ng-controller on directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a very simple angular example at http://jsfiddle.net/7eL47/3/. The rendered output of the code shows "Foobar" on the page.

The template for this rendered output is:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MenuController">
    <unordered-list>
        Foo{{foo}}
    </unordered-list>
</div>
```

However, when I change the location of `ng-controller` to the `unordered-list` as shown below, "Foobar" no longer appears--it's just "Foo." The value of `{{foo}}` is never replaced with "bar".

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <unordered-list ng-controller="MenuController">
        Foo{{foo}}
    </unordered-list>
</div>
```

Why don't I see "Foobar" still when I change the `ng-controller` directive to be on the `unordered-list` element?

Comment: Directives can have their own controllers; so I'd guess that is the reason.  I can envision a lot of nightmare problems if it were easy to just replace an internal part of a directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, `ngController` is a parent to `unordered-list`.  So it has visibility to `foo`.

Your second example:

```
<unordered-list ng-controller="MenuController">
```

Results in **two sibling scopes** each with a parent of `ngApp`.

Both your directive and the [`ngController` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1fb47e08a0eed4d4ec4638367edb08dfbcce465b/src/ng/directive/ngController.js) use `scope: true`.  `scope: true` causes a child scope to be created for that directive which inherits from the parent.  Therefore you end up with sibling scopes.

Thus, in the second example, `$scope.foo` is not visible, since it's no longer on the scope `unoderedList` inherits from (but rather on a sibling scope).